# glDrawTransformFeedbackStream, what the stream refers to?

Tags: opengl, stream, opengl-4, transform-feedback

I ported this [sample](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_400/Gl_400_transform_feedback_stream.java#L248) to to jogl from [g-truc](https://github.com/g-truc/ogl-samples) and it works, everything fine everything nice.

But now I am trying to understand exactly what the `stream` of `glDrawTransformFeedbackStream` refers to.

Basically a `vec4 position` input gets transformed to

```
        String[] strings = {"gl_Position", "Block.color"};
        gl4.glTransformFeedbackVaryings(transformProgramName, 2, strings, GL_INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS);
```

as following:

```
void main()
{   
    gl_Position = mvp * position;
    outBlock.color = vec4(clamp(vec2(position), 0.0, 1.0), 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

[transform-stream.vert](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/data/gl_400/transform-stream.vert), [transform-stream.geom](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/data/gl_400/transform-stream.geom)

And then I simply render the transformed objects with [`glDrawTransformFeedbackStream`](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_400/Gl_400_transform_feedback_stream.java#L248)

[feedback-stream.vert](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/data/gl_400/feedback-stream.vert), [feedback-stream.frag](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/data/gl_400/feedback-stream.frag)

Now, based on the [docs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawTransformFeedbackStream.xhtml) they say:

> Specifies the index of the transform feedback stream from which to
>   retrieve a primitive count.

Cool, so if I bind my `feedbackArrayBufferName` to `0` [here](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_400/Gl_400_transform_feedback_stream.java#L179)

```
    gl4.glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, feedbackName[0]);
    gl4.glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, feedbackArrayBufferName[0]);
    gl4.glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, 0);
```

I guess it should be that.

Also the geometry shader [outputs](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/data/gl_400/transform-stream.geom#L20) (only) the color to index 0. What about the positions? Are they assumed to be already on stream 0? How? From `glTransformFeedbackVaryings`?

Therefore, I tried to switch all the references to this stream to 1 to check if they are all consistent and then if they do refer to the same index.

So I modified

```
    gl4.glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 1, feedbackArrayBufferName[0]);
```

and

```
    gl4.glDrawTransformFeedbackStream(GL_TRIANGLES, feedbackName[0], 1);
```

and also inside the geometry shader

```
out Block
{
    layout(stream = 1) vec4 color;
} outBlock;
```

But if I run, I get:

```
Program link failed: 1
    Link info
---------
error: Transform feedback can't capture varyings belonging to different vertex streams in a single buffer.

OpenGL Error(GL_INVALID_OPERATION): initProgram
GlDebugOutput.messageSent(): GLDebugEvent[ id 0x502
    type Error
    severity High: dangerous undefined behavior
    source GL API
    msg GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. <program> object is not successfully linked, or is not a program object.
    when 1455183474230
    source 4.5 (Core profile, arb, debug, compat[ES2, ES3, ES31, ES32], FBO, hardware) - 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.43 - hash 0x225c78a9]
GlDebugOutput.messageSent(): GLDebugEvent[ id 0x502
    type Error
    severity High: dangerous undefined behavior
    source GL API
    msg GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. <program> has not been linked, or is not a program object.
    when 1455183474232
    source 4.5 (Core profile, arb, debug, compat[ES2, ES3, ES31, ES32], FBO, hardware) - 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.43 - hash 0x225c78a9]
```

Trying to know what'g going on, I found this [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback)

```
Output variables in the Geometry Shader can be declared to go to a particular stream. This is controlled via an in-shader specification, but there are certain limitations that affect advanced component interleaving.

No two outputs that go to different streams can be captured by the same buffer. Attempting to do so will result in a linker error. So using multiple streams with interleaved writing requires using advanced interleaving to route attributes to different buffers.
```

Is it what happens to me? `position` going to index 0 and color to index 1?

I'd simply like to know if my hypotesis are correct. And if yes, I want to prove it by changing the stream index. 
Therefore I'd also like to know how I can set the `position` on stream 1 together with color after my changes.. shall I modify the output of the geometry shader in this way `layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3, xfb_buffer = 1) out;`?

Because it complains

```
Shader status invalid: 0(11) : error C7548: 'layout(xfb_buffer)' requires "#extension GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts : enable" before use
```

Then I add it and I get

```
error: Transform feedback can't capture varyings belonging to different vertex streams in a single buffer.
```

But now they should be both on stream 1, what I am missing?

Moreover, what is the definition of a stream?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. It's all right there in plain English; the linker error doesn't seem to have much room for debate in it, and it's substantiated by the documentation you found. Do you need someone to triple-confirm it, or do you need someone to tell you how to pipe them to different buffers? And I'm not sure why you need the latter, since the paragraphs above that one in the Wiki article tell you how to do that.